# AVPlayer and black video

Tags: ios, swift, video, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I'm recording a video in the first UIViewController, writing this video to file and I want to show this video in the second UIViewController but sometimes (quite often) there is just a black frame instead of video.

`player.status.rawValue` and `player.currentItem?.status.rawValue` are 0 every time.

The file is here every time, I can process it, so `videoURL` is ok. I'm getting no errors, just the black screen.

```
    videoURLAsset = videoAsset as! AVURLAsset
    let videoURL = videoURLAsset.URL

    if playerLayer != nil {
        player = nil
        playerLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }

    player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL)
    player.volume = 0.0
    playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(10, 70, screenWidth - 20, screenHeight / 2 - 90)

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I am getting a similar problem..

Comment: I think so, but I don't remember the solution and I don't have an access to this project now, sorry :(

Comment: @Ran someone found this solution? I have the same problem...

Comment: I don't know, I am not working on that project anymore.. sorry